tns --analyticsClient VSCode debug android --start Issue "The application com.app.demo is not installed on device with identifier XXX
on VSCode after run command tns run android --device 1 the App installs and opens correctly on Physical Device.
Then I want to Attach Debug and I run the command tns --analyticsClient VSCode debug android --start
An error occurs:

The application com.app.demo is not installed on device with identifier XXX

If instead I run android on a Virtual Device and I try to run the debug command, all works fine.
I checked all the configuration and all seems to be fine.
I'm working on SAP MDK app.
